# Which security role in Dynamics CRM can disable users from modifying access teams?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am customizing Dynamics CRM, and I am modifying access teams through coding. But I don't want users to be able to add access teams from screen. I cannot find the permission for that; can someone tell me where is it in the security role?

Comment: As far as I know, user needs to have systemadmin or systemcustomizer security role to update/access Access Team. This should not be issue in your case as normal user will not have these rights? Or do your normal user can see/click through access Team. Maybe some screenshots will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to identify the security role for users to limit  the permission and remove the share privilege on that security role for that Access teams enabled entity. [Read more](https://us.hitachi-solutions.com/blog/adventures-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-access-teams/)

> You can control who can add members to the Access Team subgrid. Only users with share privilege for the entity on which the access team exists can add or remove members from the Access Team subgrid. This makes sense—by adding people to the Access Team, you are in effect sharing the record with the people on the team.

Answer (score 0):

You need a developer do that because it should modify the ribbon command in the systemuser entity.